# Getting path of a folder in Cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there any way of getting folder path (any folder and can be at any location in mac) programatically, in a native cocoa application?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to list the file system's directories to find the one you need?

Comment: Clarify your question.  Do you mean by finding all the folders that have the same name, or are you trying to let the user choose a directory?

Comment: I want to search for a folder on the disk and access all the files and subdirectories within it. I don't want to hard code it, as user can store the directory anywhere in the file system. I hope I am clear this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Did you have a look at [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? To let the user choose a directory have a look at [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I have tried NSFileManager. It gives path for Documents / Application /User directories in the file structure. I want the folder that can be either in Home directory or in Application Directory. Basically, I want to check the whole file system to check for the folder and then access it's contents. However, Accessing contents is not a problem, I am stuck at searching the folder in the system.

Comment: Or maybe this will help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719010/using-spotlight-in-cocoa)